# Django emailing every call to logging.error

Tags: python, django, logging, django-settings

Is there a way to make Django email admins about every call to `logging.error`, similar to the way it emails admins about unhandled exceptions?

Please don't offer me to create a new logger, because then I'll have to change thousands of code lines. I'm looking, hopefully, for a configuration to `settings.LOGGING`.

Comment: It sounds like you need to implement [sentry](https://getsentry.com/welcome/) or similar.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid not really, just send an email on error message

Answer (score 3):

You could try adding just the **root logger** in the django `LOGGING` setting:

```
...
'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
           'level': 'ERROR',
           'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
           'filters': ['special']
        },
        ...
}
'loggers': {
        '': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
        },
        'django.request': {
            ....
            'handlers': ['mail_admins', ...possible other handlers..],
            'propagate': False
        }
        ...
}
```

In the above sketch, the `''` logger is the root logger and `propagate` could be set to `False` for each logger that already uses the `mail_admins` handler to avoid duplicate email.

Now all loggers should also send the events to the root logger which would email admins if it's an error. This snippet is not tested, but I believe the answer lies along these lines.